# 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: centos, iptables, nginx

I ran the following iptables commands to start pptp server:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i venet0 -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i venet0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o venet0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i venet0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source 33.122.21.177
```

But it damaged the php-fpm service. Nginx returns an error “502 Bad Gateway”.  Nginx error log tells

```
failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 199.239.99.13, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
```

php-fpm service is running normally

```
service php-fpm status
php-fpm (pid  14157) is running...
```

Could  you advise me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Wait, I'm having difficulty to understand what are you trying to achieve.  To run `php-fpm` behind `nginx` you do not need `iptables` rules, you can simply run `php-fpm` on localhost (or even on a unix socket).  Moreover why do you want a `pptp` connection for?  Also, what are your configs?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

I just needed to run the command

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source 33.122.21.177
```

Comment: So, what was the issue, and how does this solve it?